# Após concluir o programa, o "textContent" some rapidamente. Minha intenção era que ficasse na tela

Tags: javascript

```js
let idadeA = document.querySelectorAll("#idadeA");


function acerteIdade(event) {
  let idadeNum = event.target.textContent;
  console.log(idadeNum)
  let outResposta = document.querySelector("#outResposta");

  if (idadeNum == '28') {
    alert('Parabéns, voçê acertou!!!')
    outResposta.textContent = `Parabéns, voçê acertou minha idade!!!`;
  } else {
    alert('errou')
    outResposta.textContent = `Voçê errou, recarregue a página e tente novamente!!!`;
  }
}
idadeA.forEach(idadeAll => {
  idadeAll.addEventListener("click", acerteIdade)
});
```

```html
<div class="container-cont">
  <h1></h1>
  <p>Qual Minha idade?:

  </p>
  <ul>
    <a href="">
      <li id="idadeA">18</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li id="idadeA">19</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li id="idadeA">20</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li id="idadeA">21</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li id="idadeA">22</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li id="idadeA">23</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li id="idadeA">24</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li id="idadeA">25</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li id="idadeA">26</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li id="idadeA">27</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li id="idadeA">28</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li id="idadeA">29</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li id="idadeA">30</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
  <h3 id="outResposta"></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quanto ao problema principal (tem vários), não está ficando a informação na tela pelo fato de vc estar utilizando uma tag `<a>`, que como pode ser visto na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) é criado um hiperlink, um link para um conteúdo especificado dentro do atributo **`href`**, como no seu exemplo este atributo está vazio, é recarregado a tela.

Fora isso existem mais problemas no seu código:

> Atributos `id` se repetindo no documento Html, o que não é recomendado, o que pode ser resolvido utilizando `classes`

> Vc tem uma função com parâmetro, logo quando for executar a mesma no `addEventListener()` terá que passar o parâmetro, que será exatamente o valor do evento do addEventListener

> Sem querer ser chato, mas, a palavra <s>você</s> é sem **`ç`**

```js
let idadeA = document.querySelectorAll('.idadeA');


function acerteIdade(event) {
  let idadeNum = event;
  let outResposta = document.querySelector('#outResposta');

  if (idadeNum === '28') {
    alert('Parabéns, você acertou!!!')
    outResposta.textContent = `Parabéns, você acertou minha idade!!!`;
  } else {
    alert('errou')
    outResposta.textContent = `Você errou, recarregue a página e tente novamente!!!`;
  }
}

idadeA.forEach(idadeAll => {
  idadeAll.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    acerteIdade(e.target.textContent);
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="container-cont">
  <h1></h1>
  <p>Qual Minha idade?:

  </p>
  <ul>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="idadeA">18</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="idadeA">19</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="idadeA">20</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="idadeA">21</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="idadeA">22</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="idadeA">23</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="idadeA">24</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="idadeA">25</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="idadeA">26</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="idadeA">27</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="idadeA">28</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="idadeA">29</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="idadeA">30</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
  <h3 id="outResposta"></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Há alguns erros em seu código:

- Uso indevido do [atributo global id](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):
  O atributo global id define um identificador **exclusivo** (ID) que **deve ser único** por todo o documento. Seu objetivo é identificar o elemento ao navegar por âncoras(usando um identificador de fragmento), quando utilizar scripts ou estilizando (com CSS).
- Uso elemento [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) como filho direto do elemento `[<ul>`][3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul):
  Mesmo que o resultado obtido em sua página seja o que deseja, semanticamente é um equívoco colocar a ancora(elemento `<a>`) dentro dentro da lista não ordenada(elemento `<ul>`). No momento os navegadores não são rígidos quanto a essa restrição porém conforme os fabricantes de browsers se adequam ao padrão W3C, essa tolerância pode ser revogada e sua página fatalmente deixará de funcionar. Os únicos elementos contidos num elemento `<ul>` devem ser [`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li), [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) e [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).
- Uso do elemento `<li>` como filho direto do elemento `<a>`:
  Mesmo que o resultado obtido em sua página seja o que deseja, semanticamente é um equívoco colocar o item de lista(elemento `<li>`) dentro da ancora(elemento `<a>`). O conteúdo de `<a>` deve ser ou [Conteúdo de Fluxo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content), ou [Conteúdo Fraseado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content) ou  [Conteúdo Interativo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#interactive_content). No momento os navegadores não são rígidos quanto a essa restrição porém conforme os fabricantes de browsers se adequam ao padrão W3C, essa tolerância pode ser revogada e sua página fatalmente deixará de funcionar.
- [Abuso das ancoras](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#onclick_events)(elemento `<a>`):
  Os elementos âncora costumam ser usados como botões falsos, definindo seu atributo `href` como `#` ou `javascript:void(0)` para evitar que a página seja atualizada e, em seguida, escute seus eventos de clique.
  Esses falsos valores de `href` causam um comportamento inesperado ao copiar, arrastar links, abrir links em uma nova guia/janela, marcar como favorito ou quando o JavaScript está carregando. Eles também transmitem semântica incorreta para tecnologias assistivas, como leitores de tela.
  Use um [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) ao invés. Em geral, você só deve usar um hiperlink para navegar para um URL real.
- Uso indevido dos [elementos de cabeçalho](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements):
  Elementos de cabeçalho(elementos de `<h1>`...`<h6>`) devem ser usados para descrever brevemente o tópico da seção em que está. Não os use para formatar texto, para isso use as propriedades [CSS para estilizar texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Fundamentals).

Sabendo disso aqui está o seu código com algumas correções semânticas no HTML, uma polida no código javascript e a aplicação de estilos CSS.

```js
let idadeA = document.querySelectorAll(".idadeA");
let outResposta = document.querySelector("#outResposta");

function acerteIdade(event) {
  let idadeNum = event.target.textContent;
  if (idadeNum == '28') {
    alert('Parabéns, você acertou!!!');
    outResposta.textContent = `Parabéns, você acertou minha idade!!!`;
  } else {
    alert('errou');
    outResposta.textContent = `Você errou, tente novamente!!!`;
  }
}

idadeA.forEach(idadeAll => {
  idadeAll.addEventListener("click", acerteIdade);
});
```

```css
.idadeA {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  display: inline;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  outline-offset: 0;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#outResposta {
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-cont">
  <p>Qual Minha idade?:</p>
  <ul>
    <li><button class="idadeA">18</button></li>
    <li><button class="idadeA">19</button></li>
    <li><button class="idadeA">20</button></li>
    <li><button class="idadeA">21</button></li>
    <li><button class="idadeA">22</button></li>
    <li><button class="idadeA">23</button></li>
    <li><button class="idadeA">24</button></li>
    <li><button class="idadeA">25</button></li>
    <li><button class="idadeA">26</button></li>
    <li><button class="idadeA">27</button></li>
    <li><button class="idadeA">28</button></li>
    <li><button class="idadeA">29</button></li>
    <li><button class="idadeA">30</button></li>
  </ul>
  <span id="outResposta"></span>
</div>
```